# PHP header not working without flush?

Tags: php, header

I'm trying to set a header with PHP like this:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Length: 1234");
?>
```

But if I open headers in Chrome with <kbd>F12</kbd>, the `content-length` is 0. Only if I call `flush()` after the `header()` method will Chrome show me the correct length. Why is that and is that a decent solution?

Comment: Check to see if you have output buffering on

Comment: @JohnConde: Wouldn't the output buffer be flushed at the end of script execution?

Comment: I would expect it to be. But I also would not expect you to need to call `flush()` either so you never know...

Comment: The `host` header is required by HTTP spec and maybe the header isn't sent because there is no output, but flush may send a \n or \r\n or something.

Comment: Do you send any HTML/text data (or it's just a blank page?)

Comment: And _is_ that the exact amount of bytes your script is outputting after that header?

Comment: That is the exact script, 1 line, i dont send any data, content-lenght is not actually 1234 but i want to set it like that. It works with flush, im wondering why not without?

Answer (score 0):

Headers require that you have sent nothing to the browser before they all have had the opportunity to become specified. If specifying a header would cause that there is information sent to the browser, then will it only be possible to send just one header element. That is not as it is designed.

So yes, you will have to give the command yourself to send your headers to the browser.
For testing purposes I consider that a decent solution. For real life web sites? No. :-)